# How can I display wide pictures in a two-column document?

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column

I have several wide pictures, and I want to show them line by line in a two-column document, like this:

[image]

I tried to use `figure*` and to control the picture's location, but it still does not work right. They were divided into several pages:

[image]

Here is my figure-related code

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1 \textwidth]{Fig_a.png}
        \caption{a living room scene optimize result; Sofas, teapoy, and television are grouped together. Chairs and table are grouped together. This scene illustrated the grouping's good interpretation of the area of use.}
        \label{Fig3}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width= 1 \textwidth]{Fig_b.png}
        \caption{a typical bedroom scene; We can see the significant of the concentration cost function in iterations from the concentration degree}
        \label{Fig4}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width= 1 \textwidth]{Fig_c.png}
        \caption{A bathroom scene optimize result; Energy field makes it possible to actively give way to the entrance to the room when the group is placed, so as to avoid the situation that the improper placement of the group makes the room entrance blocked.}
        \label{Fig5}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width= 1 \textwidth]{Fig_d.png}
        \caption{A medium-sized music classroom scene; We displayed Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes of groups}
        \label{Fig6}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: The `h` placement specifier plays no role in a `twocolumn` layout.

Comment: Could all four images fit on a single page?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to realize. @Mico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that places all four graphs and their associated captions on a single page by themselves. Note that one can get by with a single `figure*` environment.

As you didn't exactly provide a lot of information about your document's page dimensions, I've built in some flexibility the height (as a fraction of `\textheight`) the individual graphs can be and how much vertical whitespace padding should be inserted between the graphs. Please adjust as needed for your document. Omit the 'demo' option right away in your document, and omit loading the `showframe` package once you're satisfied with the "look" of the page.

The frame lines shown in the following screenshot are drawn by the `showframe` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in your real document
\usepackage{showframe} % omit this package in the your document
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\newlength\mylen

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{1pt}

%% vary the 'height' option and the '\mylen' parameter as needed:
\setkeys{Gin}{height=0.205\textheight, width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio}
\setlength\mylen{5pt}

\centering

   \includegraphics{Fig_a}
   \caption{A living room scene optimize result. Sofas, teapoy, and television are grouped together. Chairs and table are grouped together. This scene illustrated the grouping's good interpretation of the area of use.}
   \label{Fig3}

   \vspace{\mylen}

   \includegraphics{Fig_b}
   \caption{A typical bedroom scene. We can see the significant of the concentration cost function in iterations from the concentration degree}
   \label{Fig4}

   \vspace{\mylen}

   \includegraphics{Fig_c}
   \caption{A bathroom scene optimize result. Energy field makes it possible to actively give way to the entrance to the room when the group is placed, so as to avoid the situation that the improper placement of the group makes the room entrance blocked.}
   \label{Fig5}

   \vspace{\mylen}

   \includegraphics{Fig_d}
   \caption{A medium-sized music classroom scene. We displayed Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes of groups}
   \label{Fig6}
   
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to resize pictures? It works but my pictures seems were force to be resize to same scale.

Comment: @WinertozBotawar - Not knowing anything about the specifics of your graphs, I chose a solution approach that assigns the same height to all four. As long as you make the sum of the four heights equal to 0.82, i.e., 82% of `\textheight`, you can make some graphs taller (say, 0.25) and others less tall (say, 0.16).

Comment: My pictures are 4 3000x2000 pictures. I divide them into 2 parts and put them in different pages using your solution, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package:

```
    \usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{cuted}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[11]
    \begin{strip}
    \centering \includegraphics{Gauguin}
    \captionof{figure}{Gauguin}\vskip2ex
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
    \captionof{figure}{Piero di Cosimo}\vskip2ex
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Olympia}
    \captionof{figure}{Manet}
    \end{strip}

    \lipsum[12-14]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this approach allow affixing captions to graphs?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, using `\caption{figure}{…}`.

Comment: I'm working on overleaf but there seems no cuted package...

Comment: What's the difference to simply using a `minipage`?

Comment: @WinertozBotawar: Strange… It is one of the packages in the `sttools` bundle.

Comment: @OlegLobachev: As far as I know, it can break across pages, whereas a minipage can't.